# Needle probing for a convex body

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, discrete-geometry, convex-polytopes, open-problems

Suppose there is an unknown closed convex body $K$ of
volume vol$(K) = V$ inside the
unit cube $[-\frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{2}]^d$ in $\mathbb{R}^d$.
You are permitted to probe with a (one-dimensional)
ray $r$, which detects whether
$r$ includes some point of $K$, or instead if $r \cap K = \varnothing$.
My question is:

> **Q1**.
>   What is the fewest number of such
>   *needle probe* rays that guarantee
>   hitting $K$, as a function of its volume $V$?

I am especially interested in $\mathbb{R}^3$.
For example, for $V \ge \frac{1}{2}$,
one ray through the origin parallel to an axis suffices.
Here such a ray touches the boundary of a body $K$ with
vol$(K)=\frac{1}{2}$:

          
[image: NeedleCube]

To be specific:

> **Q2**. How many needle probes suffice for $V \ge \frac{1}{4}$ in $\mathbb{R}^3$?

Four parallel rays in a grid pattern do not suffice, but nine do suffice (I believe):

    
[image: Grids]

> **Q3**. In $\mathbb{R}^3$, is it sometimes more efficient to use
>   nonparallel rays?

This feels like a classic problem, but I am not finding literature.
Thanks for pointers or ideas!

**Update 1** (*28May13*). Here is Yoav Kallus' example showing that dropping the middle of the $9$ points of
the grid permits a triangle with area larger than $\frac{1}{4}$ to avoid detection:

    
[image: GridYoav]

**Update 2** (*30May13*). **Q2** and **Q3** are now answered by Benjamin Dickman and Douglas Zare: for $V=\frac{1}{4}$, three needles suffice, and more are needed for parallel needles. **Q1**, in its full generality, is difficult, and so I've added the "open problem" tag.

Comment: You realize that for small $V$, your question is at least as hard as http://mathoverflow.net/questions/3307/can-a-discrete-set-of-the-plane-of-uniform-density-intersect-all-large-triangles, don't you?

Comment: @fedja: I am, in fact, more interested in relatively large $V$, but the connection to discrepancy is very useful.  Thanks!

Comment: Do you need the center point in the arrangement of $9$ points to detect $V\ge 1/4$?

Comment: @Douglas: Excellent point! It does seem superfluous...

Comment: By the way, your earlier question is related: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/106754/detecting-a-hidden-convex-body-with-line-probes

Comment: Apologies for the overlap with earlier questions (including my own!). At least this one asks very specific questions...

Comment: @Douglas: the center point is needed. Consider the triangle with vertices at (-1/4,1/2), (-1/4,-1/4), and (1/2,-1/4). It has area 9/32 > 1/4.

Comment: @Benjamin: Certainly with the three axes as rays, $V < \frac{1}{4}$ can remain undetected. But is already difficult to see how $V \ge \frac{1}{4}$ can fit around those axes...

Comment: @Joseph: Assuming I have correctly understood your **Q2**, those three needles suffice. (Clearly it is also *necessary* to have at least three.) This should indicate your **Q3** is answered in the affirmative. Surely **Q1** is a bit tougher.

Comment: Very nice, Benjamin! 

Comment: Perhaps you may wish to edit the post so that Question 1 is emphasized. In terms of literature, it may be that the reverse scenario has been researched in greater depth: namely, finding empty convex regions in tightly packed three-space. Of course, this should be equivalent to what you are asking. I haven't read through carefully, but check out http://compgeom.com/~piyush/papers/occluder.pdf and some of the sources given in section 2 (`Previous Work').

Comment: @Benjamin: Great paper reference, new to me---Thanks! Although I do not doubt that $V=\frac{1}{4}$ is the largest convex volume avoiding those three orthogonal needles, I do not see a proof.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If $V \gt 1/2$ then there must be some pair of points $(x,y,z)$ and $(-x,-y,-z)$ contained in the region, and the convex hull of these two points contains the origin. This generalizes to show that $3$ needles connecting the centers of opposite faces (the axes) suffice for $V\gt 1/4$:

Consider the orbits of points under the volume-preserving action of changing signs. Generic points $(x,y,z)$ have orbits of size $8$: $(\pm x, \pm y, \pm z)$. If $V \gt 1/4$ then there must be some orbit so that $3/8$ of the points are contained in the region. Given any $3$ of these points, $2$ must have different signs in at least $2$ coordinates since if the first is $(x,y,z)$ and the second is $(x,y,-z)$, then the third point can't be only a single sign change away from both. If the signs differ in $2$ coordinates, suppose without loss of generality these are $(x,y,z)$ and $(x,-y,-z)$. The convex hull of these points contains the midpoint $(x,0,0)$ which is on the $x$-axis. If the points differ in $3$ signs, then their midpoint is $(0,0,0)$ on all axes.

There is a limit to how much this generalizes, but perhaps the full action of the cubic symmetries will restrict the volumes of regions which avoid the diagonals, too.

Comment: @Douglas: Very clever to consider the volume-preserving action of changing signs!